# Continual Sqlite Corruption when Using express.js on repl.it Platform

Tags: express, sqlite, replit

I'm frequently getting corruption of my Sqlite3 db when connecting with express on the repl.it platform.  I'm using a data access class -> repository pattern

snippet from app.js:

```
const AppDAO = require('./data/dao');
...
const dao = new AppDAO('./db.sqliteMaptack');
const mapTierRepo = new MapTierRepository(dao);
mapTierRepo.createTable();
```

The dao class:

```
const sqlite3 = require('sqlite3')  
const Promise = require('bluebird')

class AppDAO {  
  constructor(dbFilePath) {
    this.db = new sqlite3.Database(dbFilePath, (err) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('Could not connect to database', err);
      } else {
        console.log('Connected to database');
      }
    })
  }

  run(sql, params = []) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.db.run(sql, params, function (err) {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error running sql ' + sql);
          console.log(err);
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve({ id: this.lastID });
        }
      })
    })
  }

  get(sql, params = []) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.db.get(sql, params, (err, result) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error running sql: ' + sql);
          console.log(err);
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(result);
        }
      })
    })
  }

  all(sql, params = []) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.db.all(sql, params, (err, rows) => {
        if (err) {
          console.log('Error running sql: ' + sql);
          console.log(err);
          reject(err)
        } else {
          resolve(rows);
        }
      })
    })
  }

}

module.exports = AppDAO;
```

The repository:

```
class MapTierRepository {  
  constructor(dao) {
    this.dao = dao;
  }

  createTable() {
    const sql = 
    'CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS MapTier (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,name TEXT)';
    return this.dao.run(sql);
  }

  create(name) {
    return this.dao.run(
      'INSERT INTO MapTier (name) VALUES (?)',
      [name]);
  }

  update(mapTier) {
    const { id, name } = mapTier
    return this.dao.run(
      'UPDATE MapTier SET name = ? WHERE id = ?',
      [name, id]
    );
  }

  delete(id) {
    return this.dao.run(
      'DELETE FROM MapTier WHERE id = ?',
      [id]
    );
  }

  getById(id) {
    return this.dao.get(
      'SELECT * FROM MapTier WHERE id = ?',
      [id]);
  }

  getAll() {
    return this.dao.all('SELECT * FROM MapTier');
  }
}
module.exports = MapTierRepository;
```

All of the repository methods work.  However, when the repl.it instance crashes, its likely to cause the db to become corrupted, any thoughts?

Comment: What do you mean by corrupted? And have you figured out why your thing is crashing?

Comment: sqlite reports the file as corrupted when attempting to open it.  Its not my server that crashes its repl.it which is the host.

Comment: Can you add the full url to which your sqlite db is uploaded? Maybe its gz compressed?